# juju k8s-core deployment: Waiting for CNI plugins to become available

Tags: juju, maas, kubernetes

I am struggling with installation of juju kubernetes-core charm

I have setup three environments:

- juju-controller
- juju add-cloud manual
- added two focal Ubuntu 4 CPU 4GB RAM

Then I ran:

```
juju deploy --dry-run cs:bundle/kubernetes-core-1340 --map-machines=existing,0=0,1=1
```

and see that I am stuck in "juju status"

```
Model    Controller  Cloud/Region      Version  SLA          Timestamp
default  k8s         k8scloud/default  2.9.10   unsupported  13:08:03+02:00

App                Version         Status   Scale  Charm              Store       Channel   Rev  OS      Message
containerd         go1.13.8        active       2  containerd         charmstore  edge      147  ubuntu  Container runtime available
easyrsa            3.0.1           active       1  easyrsa            charmstore  edge      396  ubuntu  Certificate Authority connected.
etcd               3.4.5           active       1  etcd               charmstore  edge      608  ubuntu  Healthy with 1 known peer
flannel                            error        2  flannel            charmstore  edge      572  ubuntu  hook failed: "install"
kubernetes-master  1.22.0-alpha.2  waiting      1  kubernetes-master  charmstore  edge     1035  ubuntu  Waiting for CNI plugins to become available
kubernetes-worker  1.22.0-alpha.2  waiting      1  kubernetes-worker  charmstore  edge      789  ubuntu  Waiting for cluster credentials.

Unit                  Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports     Message
easyrsa/0*            active    idle   0/lxd/0  10.156.136.137            Certificate Authority connected.
etcd/0*               active    idle   0        172.16.51.212   2379/tcp  Healthy with 1 known peer
kubernetes-master/0*  waiting   idle   0        172.16.51.212             **Waiting for CNI plugins to become available**
  containerd/1        active    idle            172.16.51.212             Container runtime available
  flannel/1           error     idle            172.16.51.212             hook failed: "install"
kubernetes-worker/0*  waiting   idle   1        172.16.51.213             Waiting for cluster credentials.
  containerd/0*       active    idle            172.16.51.213             Container runtime available
  flannel/0*          error     idle            172.16.51.213             hook failed: "install"

Machine  State    DNS             Inst id               Series  AZ  Message
0        started  172.16.51.212   manual:172.16.51.212  focal       Manually provisioned machine
0/lxd/0  started  10.156.136.137  juju-c9d9ed-0-lxd-0   focal       Container started
1        started  172.16.51.213   manual:172.16.51.213  focal       Manually provisioned machine
```

When I open flannel log I see:

```
2021-08-06 10:29:20 ERROR unit.flannel/0.juju-log server.go:314 Hook error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/charms/reactive/__init__.py", line 71, in main
    bus.discover()
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 426, in discover
    _register_handlers_from_file(search_path, filepath)
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 466, in _register_handlers_from_file
    _load_module(root, filepath)
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 444, in _load_module
    return importlib.import_module(package + module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
...skipping...
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/charm/hooks/relations/kubernetes-cni/provides.py", line 5, in <module>
    from charms.layer.kubernetes_common import kubeclientconfig_path
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'charms.layer.kubernetes_common'**

2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60 Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/charm/hooks/install", line 22, in <module>
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60     main()
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/charms/reactive/__init__.py", line 71, in main
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60     bus.discover()
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 426, in discover
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60     _register_handlers_from_file(search_path, filepath)
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 466, in _register_handlers_from_file   
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60     _load_module(root, filepath)
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 444, in _load_module
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60     return importlib.import_module(package + module)
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60   File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-flannel-0/charm/hooks/relations/kubernetes-cni/provides.py", line 5, in <module>
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60     from charms.layer.kubernetes_common import kubeclientconfig_path
2021-08-06 10:54:52 WARNING unit.flannel/0.install logger.go:60 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'charms.layer.kubernetes_common'
2021-08-06 10:54:52 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation runhook.go:139 hook "install" (via explicit, bespoke hook script) failed: exit status 1
2021-08-06 10:54:52 INFO juju.worker.uniter resolver.go:144 awaiting error resolution for "install" hook
2021-08-06 10:59:52 INFO juju.worker.uniter resolver.go:144 awaiting error resolution for "install" hook
2021-08-06 10:59:52 INFO unit.flannel/0.juju-log server.go:314 Reactive main running for hook install
2021-08-06 10:59:52 ERROR unit.flannel/0.juju-log server.go:314 Hook error:
```

I am not sure why the module can not be installed or is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a k8s expert but seems that's a bug reported in: https://bugs.launchpad.net/charm-flannel/+bug/1938943

Seem's you are using `Flannel charm` and it's missing the `kubernetes_common` layer.

As they said in the Launchpad `Calico` has the `kubernetes_common` layer can you switch to `Calico charm` if you don't specifically need the `Flannel` as a workaround?

Detailed information: https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/charm-calico

**Edit:** Alternatively you can add `layer:kubernetes-common` to [layer.yaml](https://github.com/charmed-kubernetes/charm-flannel/blob/master/layer.yaml) and build the charm :)

Comment: thank you very much for answer! it looks the fix is on the way 

https://github.com/charmed-kubernetes/charm-flannel/pull/73/commits/fa3e57d60d194d8c5bc099495958f448c02c5ecc

so i will wait for merge and try again :)

Comment: @Viktorbs It seems its already merged but `in progress` in Launchpad so initial release can take time as you said :) If this answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking to tick button. Have a nice day!